# reports in PDF with tables in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, reporting

I have to generate few reports in PDF format with some inventory stats (no graphs, only tables). Additionally, I have to generate some pdf labels for the placed orders and units in a nice tabular format (taking care of landscape orientation and line wrapping) for the web platform. Which PHP API/Library would be best suitable for this purpose. I am using Zend framework but Zend's PDF API is not rich enough to serve the cause.

One option I am considering is to use LateX for generating PDFs.
Advices? Suggestions?

Comment: you can try [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default).

Answer (score 0):

There are several PDF generation libraries and executables.
I've used:

- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
- [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)
- [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) as @redreggae suggested
- [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)
- Many other alive & dead solutions

They all rendered HTML to PDF. The problem of all (except wkhtmltopdf) was that they all used different (non-standard) rendering engines and results were often different between them and unsatisfying. `wkhtmltopdf` uses [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) to interpret the HTML and create a pdf file. I personally prefer `wkhtmltopdf` after trying/using (in production) all other of the ones listed.. There is one drawback to it - it is an executable and as such it must be called with `exec()` however this should not be a big issue when proper coding is applied such that you prevent code injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something higher level than HTML to PDF converters, you can try [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML), it's a renderer for JasperReports on pure PHP.